# How to validate my contact form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I used this code to connect my contact form to mysql but the problem is I don't know how to validate each item like the name has to be fill or the email should be valid so it will not bother me later when I take care all of it, here is my code :can you help me :

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You could take a look into **http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/**

Comment: this looks good , show your html form

Comment: There are tons of tutorials about form validation. You could do a little research on google.

Comment: You should be looking into PHP's [`filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) functions.

Comment: At start please avoid jquery validation, cause it validates only in frontend, and you know its easily to change front end on webpage, so in fact, you should validate on both sides, front end and back end! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have client side validation (e.g using jquery)

and in your php you can try like this:

```
   if(!empty($_POST['lastname']) &&  !empty($_POST['age']) &&  !empty($_POST['firstname']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
    VALUES
    ('mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[firstname])','mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[lastname])','mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[age])')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

You can validate email in php like this:

```
filter_var($emailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

[php filter](http://www.php.net/filter_var)

Comment: so I just need to add "mysql_real_escape_string" thanks, it seems simple and I'll try it soon

Comment: no you also need first condition to check if all data is available

Comment: by the way, where should I put "filter_var($emailAddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)" in my code ? @awlad

Comment: where you need to validate email

Comment: I need to validate it right after "$_POST[age]" @awlad

Comment: is it possible ?  @awlad

Answer (score 0):

For proper validation of a form, some aspects have to be taken into account, to help filter an excess of garbage input. My approach is this:

First of all, check the minimum lenght of the text. This way, you decrease the risk of getting meaningless input. Secondly, check the maximum lenght of the text; you don't want someone flooding your database with a ton of text just for fun. And thirdly, you should use regular expressions to check proper formats for the different fields (a postal code, a phone number, an e-mail) and very important, allow only characters that are required in that field, to avoid or minimize the risk of someone sending miserable cross-site injections thru the input.

Here an orientative example:

```
function validate_form() {
$errors = array();
// El nombre del usuario es necesario
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['user_name']))) {
$errors[] = 'The username is required.';
}
// El nombre del usuario no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('@[^a-zA-Z0-9_\- ]@', trim($_POST['user_name']))) {
$errors[] = 'The username cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// El nombre del usuario no debe tener menos de 3 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['user_name'])) < 3) {
$errors[] = 'The username cannot have less than 3 characters long.';
}
// El nombre del usuario no debe tener más de 24 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['user_name'])) > 24) {
$errors[] = 'The username cannot have more than 24 characters long.';
}
// La contraseña es necesaria
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['password']))) {
$errors[] = 'The password is required.';
}
// La contraseña no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('@[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]@', trim($_POST['password']))) {
$errors[] = 'The password cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// La contraseña no debe tener menos de 6 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) < 6) {
$errors[] = 'The password cannot have less than 6 characters long.';
}
// La contraseña no debe tener más de 12 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) > 12) {
$errors[] = 'The password cannot have more than 12 characters long.';
}
// La contraseña debe contener letras y números
if (! preg_match('/([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])+/', trim($_POST['password']))) {
$errors[] = 'The password must contain letters and numbers.';
}
// Password y Password Check deben ser iguales
if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password_check']) { 
$errors[] = 'Password and Password Check do not match.';
}
// El correo electrónico es necesario
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['e_mail']))) {
$errors[] = 'The e-mail is required.';
}
// El correo electrónico no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-@\.]/', trim($_POST['e_mail']))) {
$errors[] = 'The e-mail cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// El correo electrónico no debe tener más de 64 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['e_mail'])) > 64) {
$errors[] = 'The e-mail cannot have more than 64 characters long.';
}
// El correo electrónico debe tener un formato correcto
if (! preg_match('/[^@\s]{3,}@([-a-z0-9]{3,}\.)+[a-z]{2,}/', trim($_POST['e_mail']))) {
$errors[] = 'The e-mail must have a valid format.';
}
// El país seleccionado debe ser válido
if (! array_key_exists($_POST['country'], $GLOBALS['countries'])) {
$errors[] = 'Please select a valid country.';
}
// La ciudad es necesaria
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['city']))) {
$errors[] = 'The city is required.';
}
// La ciudad no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('@[^a-zA-Z\- ]@', trim($_POST['city']))) {
$errors[] = 'The city cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// La ciudad no debe tener menos de 3 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['city'])) < 3) {
$errors[] = 'The city cannot have less than 3 characters long.';
}
// La ciudad no debe tener más de 64 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['city'])) > 64) {
$errors[] = 'The city cannot have more than 64 characters long.';
}
// El mes seleccionado debe ser válido
if (! array_key_exists($_POST['month'], $GLOBALS['months'])) {
$errors[] = 'Please select a valid month.';
}
// El día seleccionado debe ser válido
if (! array_key_exists($_POST['day'], $GLOBALS['days'])) {
$errors[] = 'Please select a valid day.';
}
// El año seleccionado debe ser válido
if (! array_key_exists($_POST['year'], $GLOBALS['years'])) {
$errors[] = 'Please select a valid year.';
}
// El nombre real del usuario es necesario
if (! strlen(trim($_POST['real_name']))) {
$errors[] = 'Your real name is required.';
}
// El nombre real del usuario no debe contener caracteres problemáticos
if (preg_match('@[^a-zA-Z\- ]@', trim($_POST['real_name']))) {
$errors[] = 'Your real name cannot contain invalid characters.';
}
// El nombre real del usuario debe tener menos de 3 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['real_name'])) < 3) {
$errors[] = 'Your real name cannot have less than 3 characters long.';
}
// El nombre real del usuario no debe tener más de 64 caracteres
if (strlen(trim($_POST['real_name'])) > 64) {
$errors[] = 'Your real name cannot have more than 64 characters long.';
}
// El número CAPTCHA introducido debe ser correcto
$captcha_num_1 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 0, 1);
$captcha_num_2 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 1, 1);
$captcha_num_3 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 2, 1);
$captcha_num_4 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 3, 1);
$captcha_num_5 = substr($_POST['captcha'], 4, 1);
if (($_SESSION['num1'] != crypt($captcha_num_1, $_SESSION['num1'])) || 
($_SESSION['num2'] != crypt($captcha_num_2, $_SESSION['num2'])) ||
($_SESSION['num3'] != crypt($captcha_num_3, $_SESSION['num3'])) ||
($_SESSION['num4'] != crypt($captcha_num_4, $_SESSION['num4'])) ||                                                                            ($_SESSION['num5'] != crypt($captcha_num_5, $_SESSION['num5']))) {
$errors[] = 'The CAPTCHA number entered is not correct.';
}
// El nombre de usuario y la dirección de e-mail deben ser únicos en la base de datos
global $db;
$sql = 'SELECT user_name, e_mail FROM users';
$q = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($q)) {
if ($users->user_name == $_POST['user_name']) {
$errors[] = 'This username already exists in the database. Please use a different one.';
}
if ($users->e_mail == $_POST['e_mail']) {
$errors[] = 'This e-mail address already exists in the database. Please use a different one.';
}
}
}
// Si hay errores, resetear el CAPTCHA
if (is_array($errors)) {                                                                             reset_captcha();
}
return $errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following answer

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
$c=0;
if($_POST['firstname']=="")
{
$msg='Please enter firstname';
$c++;
}
if($_POST['lastname']=="")
{
$msg1='Please enter lastname';
$c++;
}
if($_POST['age']=="")
{
$msg2='Please enter age';
$c++;
}
if($c==0)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Print $msg,$msg1,$msg2 in respective places